# See me once, see me twice

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, knowledge

A very short riddle just came to my mind, let's see if it can be cracked:

> see me once, food can usually be found
>   see me twice, thundering typhoons all around

hints are coming daily, if needed. Good Luck!

Although this riddle is already solved, here is a hint. (For the people reusing this riddle):

> see me once, you'll need more than your hands
>   see me twice, experience adventures in all kinds of lands

<sub>To go to the sequel, [click here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/72536/49661)</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could you be

> **Tin**?

*"See me once, food can usually be found"*

> **Tin**s can contain tinned/canned foods

*"see me twice, thundering typhoons all around"*

> Thundering Typhoons is [part of a curse used by Captain Haddock](https://www.etsy.com/listing/495242260/tintin-captain-haddock-t-shirt) in **Tintin**. "Billions of bilious blue blistering barnacles in a thundering typhoon!". [Captain Haddock is known for his curses](http://tintin.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Captain_Haddock%27s_Curses) :)

Also,

> Haddock is also a fish, which is a food that can come in a **tin/can**.

or something along these lines?

Comment: Indeed I am! Well done!

Comment: Awesome! That was a nice puzzle. I've never gotten one of these right before :)

Comment: This was it? Dammit, Capt'n!

Answer (score 2):

## Partial Answer:

Could you be a

> **HOLE**?

`see me once, food can usually be found`

> The hole in this case is a **bin**.

`see me twice, thundering typhoons all around`

> The hole in this case is the **centre of a typhoon**!

This does not really explain the "see me once, see my twice" part.

---

As confirmed by OP,

> It is not rain, either.

But, having another guess, could it be

> **FAST**?

`see me once, food can usually be found`

> **FAST FOOD**.

`see me twice, thundering typhoons all around`

> **Winds are fast** in a typhoon.

`"See me once, see me twice"`

> There is **fast** and then **fast fast**?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not that. The "see me once, see me twice" part is a crucial clue to get the answer

Comment: @Cashbee I edited another answer :)

Comment: funny idea with the food, but no. Getting warmer though

Comment: @Cashbee hahah, I've got no idea xD. I'll figure it out, though.. hmm.. :{

Answer (score 2):

Quasi-jokey answer, but are you

> Cane?

see me once, food can usually be found

> As in sugar cane or candy cane

see me twice, thundering typhoons all around

> As in the ‘Canes (Carolina Hurricanes)!

A different less jokey answer could be

> BORA?

see me once, food can usually be found

> Bora is the Guyanese name for the asparagus bean.

see me twice, thundering typhoons all around

> Bora Bora is in the Pacific near the typhoons.

Comment: Wow I really love both of your answers, all your explanations make perfect sense for both. I guess I need to make it a little less broad. Unfortunately it's not my intended answer.

Comment: @Cashbee thanks for the encouragement! Could you provide a hint possibly to narrow down the answer? (Or in 24 hours, if you’d rather people have a chance to crack the riddle as-is!)

Comment: Yes I will add the first hint soon (today). If there is one more wrong answer with good explanation like yours, the hint will come even sooner.