# See me once, see me twice #2

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge

I had a lot of fun with my "see me once, see me twice" question, so I thought I'd make a series out of them.

So here is the next riddle:

> see me once, the hammer falls.
>   see me twice, the gamer calls.

As last time, it starts with only one 2-liner. Additional hints will be given almost hourly.

First Hint:

> see me once, and I'm hidden inside
> see me twice, game over is implied

Second Hint:

> see me once, when I'm lighter than a plum
> see me **thrice**, out of the tunnel you come

Third Hint:   (and last one for today)

> the "see me once" part refers to a different meaning of me in every two-liner

Last Hints:

> the see-me-once in the first hint feels really good when found.
> What *don't* you have in tunnels? It doesn't matter whether you're in a train or a car

See the last one in the series: [See me once, see me twice #1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/72528/49661)

Comment: I'm starting to get the idea now, but I can't seem to wrap my head around this... hmm...

Comment: @user477343 I made this one a little harder, because the meaning of "seeing once or twice" is now clear (if you look at the [previous question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/72528/49661))

Comment: I can tell :P ${}$

Comment: Since this appears to be quite hard, the first hint was now already added. @user477343

Comment: Somebody upvote again! It is an awesome riddle and DVL12, so I can't upvote. Get the OP past the $1$,$000$ rep milestone! :D ... **Edit:** Thanks @El-Guest!

Comment: Upvoted! Great Question!

Comment: Oh, and @El-Guest, expect to see $+50$ rep soon... :P

Comment: haha thanks guys. this calls for a 1k rep party!

Comment: I think See me once somehow relates to rot13(anvy), because of `the hammer falls` and `I'm hidden inside`

Comment: As promised, a wild hint appeared. Is it super effective?

Comment: Added a third hint, which will be the last one for today. More hints will come in 1 to 2 days if requested.

Comment: Another great question! I'm dying here.
I thought maybe it could be to do with rot13(gur zbba? - unzzre qebc rkcrevzrag, uvqqra vafvqr fyrrcvat ng avtug, yrff tenivgl/jrvtug, gjvpr n zbagu vf n sbegavtug juvpu fbhaqf yvxr sbegavgr) but that is incredibly forced... 
Also had thoughts like rot13(Znevb xbbcn gebbcnf - fbzr bs gurz sybng ba pybhqf (yvggyr jrvtug), naq puhpx unzzref, uneq gb xvyy (tnzr bire, rfc vs gurer ner 2?) gurl ergerng vafvqr gurve furyyf vs whzcrq ba, Znevb pbzrf bhg bs ghaaryf/cvcrf) and maybe clues relate to appearance order in-game?
Looking forward to the solution :)

Comment: @Namtys interesting ideas. Both too forced.. please put these thoughts in a partial (or even whole) answer, as long as theyre not asking me for clarification. It could help others piecing together the answer, even if your guess was wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you

> **G**

See me once

> the hammer falls -> **G**, a unit for gravity
>  I'm hidden inside -> ummm, well...the **g**-spot?
>  I'm lighter than a plum -> **g**, a unit for weight (gram)

See me twice

> the gamer calls, game over is implied -> **gg** ("good game") is often said when a match ends in gaming

See me thrice

> out of the tunnel you come -> I think this refers to **3G** phone service, which you would lose while traveling through a tunnel

Comment: The anser is correct! But some of the clues are not yet correct: rot(tyhba naq ttt)

Comment: G is a musical note, which can be played on a piano, an instrument that uses hammers to hit strings.

Comment: Your answer will only be accepted once you find the rest of the clues.

Comment: I have added hints to help you find the last clues.

Comment: That edit looks good! All the clues solved!