# See me once, see me twice #3

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge

You guys seem to like these riddles, so here you have another one:

> See me once, the winged creatures visiting.
>   See me twice, small children's eyes glistening.
>   See me four times, are you even listening?

<sub>Here are the previous riddles in this series (the solutions there have nothing to do with this one).

[#1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/72528/49661)

[#2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/72536/49661)</sub>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are

> LA

See me once, the winged creatures visiting.

> LA stands for the city Los Angeles, "the angels".

See me twice, small children's eyes glistening.

> LALA land is used to mean a fantasy world, often related to kids.

See my four times, are you even listening?

> LALALALA while plugging your ears.

Comment: Indeed I am! Nicely done. I had another explanation in mind for the see me twice though. Rot13(Ynyn ynaq vf abg sbe fznyy xvqf rfcrpvnyyl)

Comment: @Cashbee It wouldn't happen to be a reference to rot13(gur Gryrghoovrf punenpgre), would it?

Comment: According to Wikipedia at least, that name is spelled differently, so it could be a bit of a stretch, but I like that idea and that might be it anyway!

Comment: OH. i guess I didnt do my research part well enough. Yes that is what i meant

Answer (score 2):

Bit of a stretch but are you

> **UP**?

Explanation:

See me once, the winged creatures visiting.

> You often need to look **up** in order to see winged creatures like birds in the sky.

See me twice, small children's eyes glistening.

> Small children will often say "**up up**" when they want to be picked up. Their eyes could be glistening with affection or because they are about to cry and want to be comforted.

See me four times, are you even listening?

> Similar to the previous answer, if you ignore/don't listen to a kid saying "up up", they are likely to repeat it more fervently. "**Up up! UP UP!**"

Comment: No, that's not it. I like your explanation for see me twice ^^

Comment: I agree with @Cashbee. It's very cute :}