# See me once, you squeal with glee

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, knowledge

> See me once, you squeal with glee
> See me twice, a foul apple I see
>
> See me twice, do not pass go
> Hear me thrice, swing up the radio

First hint:

> Both 'see me twice' lines refer to the same thing!

Second hint:

> The apple is quite huge!

---

<sub>Here are the previous riddles in this series (the solutions there have nothing to do with this one, only the process of getting there).

[#1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/72528/49661) , [#2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/72536/49661),
[#3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/72565/49661)</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is the answer

> Sing

See me once, you squeal with glee

> Sing is a quite joyful movie

See me twice, a foul apple I see

> The "quite huge apple" of the hint is New York, the state in which the prison of Sing Sing is

See me twice, do not pass go

> Since Sing Sing is a jail, well, you do not pass go

Hear me thrice, swing up the radio

> The song Sing Sing Sing by Benny Goodman surely makes you turn up the volume

**Edit**

> The first line coul also refer to "Sing!", a song from the series Glee. I honestly never heard about that, the Great Internet told me...

Comment: A good one. Matches really well.

Comment: Indeed I am! There is another explanation for the first line, can you find it? As soon as you do, I will accept this answer. Well played!

Comment: I was not very sure about that. Edited!

Comment: rot13(vg'f abg nobhg gur fbat cre fr, ohg zber nobhg gur frevrf tyrr juvpu vf nyy nobhg fvatvat. Guvf pbhagf.) - Really well done! And welcome to Puzzling.SE!

Answer (score 1):

Are you:

> <s>Snow</s> The letter C

*See me once, you squeal with glee*

> <s>When it starts snowing (particularly in places where it doesn't snow often), people often squeal with glee.</s>  Christmas!

*See me twice, a foul apple I see*

> <s>The tale of Snow White involves a poisoned apple.</s> Not sure.

*See me twice, do not pass go*

> Community Chests or Chance Cards in Monopoly, can send you to jail, and you do not pass go.

*Hear me thrice, swing up the radio*

> Not sure of this either.

Comment: Intersting, but no. Look at previous riddles in this series  to see what is meant with 'see me twice' - rot13(Vg jbhyq or 'fabjfabj' va lbhe pnfr)

Comment: still no, sorry ;)

Comment: gah. I'm bad at this ><