# See me once, see me twice #5

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, knowledge

Here I am again with a fifth See me once riddle. Have fun finding the answer!

> see me once, I'm taped together as a twist.
>   see me twice, used by both chef and geologist.
>
> see me once, icky sticky but everywhere in use.
>   see me twice, my subjects I like to abuse.

Although the answer has already been found, here is a hint. (For the people reusing this riddle. Answers here do not have to include this hint - but feel free if you want to):

> see me once, some people like to inhale
>   see me twice, eat me fresh or else I go stale

<sub>Here are the previous riddles in this series (the solutions there have nothing to do with this one, only the process of getting there).

[#1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/72528/49661), [#2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/72536/49661), [#3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/72565/49661), [#4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/72609/49661)</sub>

Comment: Been a while; maybe time for a hint?

Comment: It's only been 8 hours. Usually better to wait about a day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are:

> Tar

see me once, I'm taped together as a twist.

> "Tar Tape" used around the handle of a baseball bat.

see me twice, used by both chef and geologist.

> Tartar sauce and Cream of Tartar

see me once, icky sticky but everywhere in use.

> Used on roads everywhere

see me twice, my subjects I like to abuse.

> tartar : a person of irritable or violent temper.

Comment: Yes I am! I'm not sure if I understand your explanation for the first clue. I'll accept your answer when you get that one right.

Comment: I updated my guess for first clue to be more specific.  If that's not what you had in mind, I'm not sure what it would be.

Comment: What I had in mind was rot13(gncr nepuvir (gne)) but yours makes sense too I guess :)

Comment: I actually thought about that!  But didn't get the twist part :)

Comment: the twist was only for rhyming reasons :)