# See Me Once, See Me Twice #6 - Fanmade

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

This is another see me once, see me twice riddle that has been done by @Cashbee. Here is a [link](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73106/see-me-once-see-me-twice-5) to the last one done by them.

> See me once, I am a change, 
>  See me twice, changes have already been made.
>   
>  See me once, I am 4, 
>  See me twice, I am 6 and 2. 
>  See me once, I could be done here. 
>  See me twice, people have done this here.

---

Hopefully this isn't too tricky. Thought of it on the way home last night and thought it could be interesting. Good Luck!

Comment: Yay a fanmade one, what an honour! Very creative, +1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the answer might be

> Edit

See me once, I am a change,

> An **edit** is a change

See me twice, changes have already been made.

> *Editedit* = Edited it

See me once, I am 4,

> **Edit** is four letters long.

See me twice, I am 6 and 2.

> **Edited it** is six and then two letters.

See me once, I could be done here.

> I am writing this in an **edit**,

See me twice, people have done this here.

> People **edit** questions and answers here all the time.

Comment: 1+ Nice, Even I thought of Edit, but I didn't manage to figure the I am 4 and I am 6 & 2