# See me once, See me Twice #7

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge

Here I am again, with another See me once riddle. Have fun!

> See me once, at the start of the week
> See me twice, the men becoming bleak
>
> See me once, when gambling on chinese ground
> See me twice, saved but lost time I found

First Hint:

> See me once, my dice are divine my friend
> See me twice, my brother's story would never end

<sub>Here are the previous riddles in this series (the solutions there have nothing to do with this one, only the process of getting there).

[#1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/72528/49661), [#2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/72536/49661), [#3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/72565/49661), [#4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/72609/49661), [#5](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/73106/49661), [#6](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/73521/49661)</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See me once, at the start of the week, when gambling on Chinese ground, my dice are divine.

> Mo - may be short for Monday.
>  mo - the ISO code and Internet country code top-level domain for Macau.
>  [Mo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mo_(divination)) - Tibetan divination which uses dice.

See me twice, the men becoming bleak, saved lost time I found, my brother's story would never end.

> This suggests the novel [Momo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momo_(novel)), also know as The Grey Gentlemen, by Michael Ende. Momo is a girl who saves her society from the sinsister Men in Grey who are stealing the time of humans.
>  Michael Ende also wrote The Neverending Story, centred on the boy Bastian Balthazar Bux.

Comment: Nicely done! Since you found the correct answer and every clue you explained is correct, can you also explain the very last line - "my brother's story would never end"? I know you can do it :)

Comment: @Cashbee, I should've got that - translated into over 40 languages,  and over 10 million in circulation.

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer is

> Sun

*See me once, at the start of the week*

> Depending on when you start your week, it might start with **Sun**day

*See me twice, the men becoming bleak*

> If you see the **sun** twice, you're likely gonna be bleak or tired

I dunno the rest, but I think I'm allowed to post this.

Comment: Not the correct answer, but yes you are allowed to post this :) See the previous riddles in the series to find the meaning of the phrase "see me twice".

Answer (score 2):

I think it's

> R

See me once, at the start of the week

> Sunday, which is abbreviated with R

See me twice, the men are becoming bleak

> I think this stands for re-roll, as in rerolling a character in a game, because your last character was either finished or failed?

See me once, when gambling on Chinese ground

> R for renminbi, the currency of the people's republic of China

See me twice, saved but lost time I found

> Rereading something, saving yourself from a mistake but lost time by having to reread it

Comment: interesting idea, but a little stretched :) No, that's not it.