# See me once, See me twice #8

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, knowledge

> See me once, I like riddles so don't be a buzzkill
>   See me twice, tell everyone because I'm really ill

First hint:

> See me once, when hit I do a spiral
> See me twice, when hip I do go viral

I am prepared to give out more hints if needed. Good luck!

<sub>Here are the previous riddles in this series (the solutions there have nothing to do with this one, only the process of getting there).

[#1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/72528/49661), [#2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/72536/49661), [#3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/72565/49661), [#4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/72609/49661), [#5](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/73106/49661), [#6](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/73521/49661), [#7](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/74120/49661)</sub>

Comment: Warning: this riddle does no longer work, as it was based on a previous username of mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the solution was hidden in plain sight... ;)

> **Me**

*See me once, I like riddles so don't be a buzzkill*

> As previous answers have stated, that's Cashbee, the OP - AKA "**Me**"

*See me twice, tell everyone because I'm really ill \ See me twice, when hip I do go viral*

> That would be a **Meme**, which you send everyone and it goes viral (aka "ill").

*See me once, See me twice*

> This whole solution was *right there* in the title :)

*See me once, when hit I do a spiral*

...That's the only part I haven't really figured out yet. But here's a possibility:

> M.E. is short for [Main Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_main_engine) on space shuttles, and when it's damaged I guess it could send them into a spin?

Comment: The answer is correct :) The spiral clue is the hardest, and I didn't really expect that one to be solved. it refers to rot13(gur trezna zrffrefpuzvgg nve svtugre)

Answer (score 6):

Are you a:

> **BEE**

*See me once, I like riddles so don't be a buzzkill*

> **BEE**, referring to OP, Cashbee, as they like riddles, and also buzz like a bee.

*See me twice, tell everyone because I'm really ill*

> **BB** which stands for Bardet-Biedl syndrome, an illness.

Comment: rot13(lbh ner ba gur evtug genpx)

Comment: This answer is not correct, but not completely wrong either. I have added a hint.

Comment: am I doing the "see me twice" thing correctly?

Comment: both parts are incorrect, but the explanation of the first hits the nail on the head

Comment: it does fit though +1 nice guess

Answer (score 3):

Here's a long shot, but:

> Cash

See me once, I like riddles so don't be a buzzkill

> reference to OP. Based on @AHKieran's idea

See me twice, tell everyone because I'm really ill

> Cash Cash is apparently a band. And ill is synonymous with sick, which is sometimes used to mean "cool". Generally fan bases appreciate bands and like to spread the word that they've spotted said band.

Hint part 1:

> When you flick a coin, it spins but runs along a spiral path.

Hind part 2:

> Band songs sometimes go "viral" on the web, such as youtube.