# I'm the first of my kind

Tags: riddle

> See me once, I'm the first of my kind
> See me twice, unhealthy lives we left behind
>
> See me once, because there's only one
> See me twice, then there's something we shun

Hint:

> See me once, some mistake me for a mountaintop
> See me thrice, without me many devices flop

Good Luck!

<sub>Here are the previous riddles in this series (the solutions there have nothing to do with this one, only the process of getting there).

[#1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/72528/49661), [#2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/72536/49661), [#3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/72565/49661), [#4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/72609/49661), [#5](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/73106/49661), [#6](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/73521/49661), [#7](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/74120/49661), [#8](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/74379/49661)</sub>

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe you are:

> the letter 'a'

See me once, I'm the first of my kind

> First letter in the alphabet

See me twice, unhealthy lives we left behind

> AA stands for alcoholics anonymous which helps recovering addicts

See me once, because there's only one

> use the word a when there is one of an item( a chair, a table , etc.)

See me twice, then there's something we shun

> <strike>not sure for this part but maybe AA like a scream or shout?</strike> <strike>People tend to ignore/not help AA and in a sense shun it.</strike> Hopefully third times the charm: People in AA shun alcohol?

Hints:
See me once, some mistake me for a mountaintop

> A capital A looks like a cartoonish mountain

See me thrice, without me many devices flop

> As pointed out by @El-Guest AAA batteries are commonly used in devices to power them

Comment: Nice answer!! Then the once hint refers to the funcr of your answer, and the thrice hint refers to onggrevrf.

Comment: @El-Guest Thank you! I just saw the hints after posting and couldn't think of what the second hint meant!

Comment: rot13(obgu gjvpr-pyhrf ersre gb gur fnzr guvat)

Comment: @gabbo1092 Great answer! I could only guess the answer because of the hints :)

Comment: @VivekParekh Thanks! I had been thinking about the question for awhile and came back to look at it and everything just clicked all of a sudden

Comment: I'm not sure how much I should help with the last incorrect clue (You know which one). Maybe think about who 'we' refers to in that line. But anyways, congratulations on solving the riddle and even half a minute before I added the hint :)

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> Alphabet A?

See me once, I'm the first of my kind

> First letter of the alphabet

See me once, some mistake me for a mountaintop

> the top of the alphabet A looks like a mountain

See me thrice, without me many devices flop

> AAA batteries. As in batteries; without which devices fails