# I can be a number

Tags: riddle, word

> See me once, I don't want to, shoo!
> See me twice, care what you say, for I'm a taboo
>
> See me once, I can be a number
> See me twice, the sports team likes to slumber

Hints will come bidaily. Good Luck!

<sub>If you are not familiar with my See me once riddles, I recommend you first have a look at the latest riddles in this series:

[#6](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/73521/49661), [#7](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/74120/49661), [#8](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/74379/49661), [#9](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/74612/49661)</sub>

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See me once, I don't want to, shoo! See me twice, care what you say, for I'm a taboo.

> No! - as in go away.
>  no-no - a taboo

See me once, I can be a number. See me twice, the sports team likes to slumber.

> No. is an abbreviation for number.
>  A no-no in baseball is a game in which the pitcher does not allow any hits.

Comment: Tom, you see through my riddles as if they were out of glass! I'll accept your answer in a bit. Well done!

Comment: @Cashbee: Q1. See me once your format is good, see me twice your format is sweet. More personally, Q2. See me once I'm a cat, see me twice I'm a drum :P

Comment: Oh dear, give me some time to understand :D

Comment: shame on me, but I don't get it. Unless you mean the band purrpurr :) Can I haz a hint?

Comment: @Cashbee I think it's my bad puzzle as it is two separate questions/answers. Q1 Is  good but French. Q2 is something personal to me!

Comment: oh, I think i get the second now, that was totally my bad for not getting it, as I know both terms, hahaha. the first one evades me though (I do speak french a bit)

Comment: @Cashbee, rot13(tbbtyr genafyngr tbbq)

Comment: @SeanC I know what good means in French, but I can't see the relation to the riddle. I'll just assume it's a compliment on my riddle series format :)

Comment: @Cashbee, rot13(obaoba) is a sweet

Comment: @ahaha there are multiple translations for good. I was thinking of bien. (so did google translator). Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

Partial Answer:

> G?

I can be a number:

> Graham's number?

Sports team slumber:

> as in GG (Good Game)?

Comment: hehe, I already made [a riddle with that answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/72536/49661) :)

Answer (score 3):

I think I have something!

> 0 (the number)

See me once, I don’t want to, shoo!

> Still not sure

See me twice, care what you say, for I’m a taboo,

> Well, saying “00” in mathematics without anything in front is generally frowned upon.

See me once, I could be a number

> It is a number

See me twice, the sports team likes to slumber

> after a 0-0 score, the sports teams seem like they’re almost asleep

Comment: It's not the answer, but coincidentally one of the clue explanations is actually correct :)