# I'm half high, but what am I?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> See me once, with two joints, already half high
> See me twice, as a part of the toast that the people will cry
>
> See me once, at concerts, but not Bob Marley's
> See me twice, aren't these some cheerful parties?

Hints will be added after 1 day, if needed. Have fun!

<sub>If you are not familiar with my See me once riddles, I recommend you first have a look at the latest riddles in this series:

[#7](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/74120/49661), [#8](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/74379/49661), [#9](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/74612/49661), [#10](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/74641/49661)</sub>

Comment: The answer better be [Towelie](https://i.redd.it/gzqizvf3qq3x.jpg).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you:

> Hip

*See me once, with two joints, already half high*

> Hip joints, half way up your body.

*See me twice, as a part of the toast that the people will cry*

> HipHip, Hooray!

*See me once, at concerts, but not Bob Marley's*

> you see hip at HipHop concerts. But Bob Marley does Reggae

*See me twice, aren't these some cheerful parties?*

> HipHip, Hooray! (this time, at a party)

Comment: I would disagree on the bob marley thing! :-) You'll need to go over that clue again, but the green tick will belong to you!

Comment: @Cashbee i have no idea what else it could be :(

Comment: Seeing how your explanation makes sense too but is just not what I meant, I'll turn a blind eye and help you with that a bit: What genre is the sound of bob marley?

Comment: Try Rot13(uvc ubc)  fo the Bob Marley clue.

Comment: mmh, it's still not quite right. rot13(lbh frr uvc ng UvcUbc pbapregf. Ohg Obo Zneyrl qbrf Erttnr). Again my reasoning for providing you the explanation is only because your own explanation made sense too.

Comment: Rot13(Obo zneyrl jnf n Uvccvr) - So you could see him at the concerts