# See me once, See me Twice #12

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> See me once, I'm watching your every move
>   Thanks for your visit, I know you were there
>   I see what you did there in my lair
>   Look for my acronym and you'll have your proof.
>
> See me twice, almost glorious, a pretty cat
>   thousands of reasons for hiding my hand
>   Maybe it's time for my outfit to be bland
>   I can dive but not very deep, I guess I was born like that.

Hint:

> See me once, my lair is in the cloud
>  See me twice, find my songs in shroud

<sub>If you are not familiar with my See me once riddles, I recommend you first have a look at the latest riddles in this series and their solutions:

[#7](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/74120/49661), [#8](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/74379/49661), [#9](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/74612/49661), [#10](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/74641/49661), [#11](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/74647/49661)</sub>

Comment: I added a hint for each paragraph. However, I did not want to make it too easy. It's still quite a tough nut to crack even with the hints.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Partial Answer:

> Ga

---

My reasoning:

"See Me Once" Overall Meaning:

> GA could stand for "Google Analytics"

See me once, I'm watching your every move

> Google analytics watches you through every website you visit.

Thanks for your visit, I know you were there

> Again, google analytics tracks you once you visit a site by using cookies.

I see what you did there in my lair

> The lair could mean "the internet", again google analytics tracking you.

Look for my acronym, and you'd have my proof.

> And yeah, "GA" could stand for Google Analytics.

Hint:

> See me once, my lair is in the cloud
>  The cloud is another way of saying a web server, for hosting google analytics.

---

"See Me Twice" Overall Meaning:

> I'm thinking of Lady Gaga, and the verb "to go gaga" over something

See me twice, almost glorious, a pretty cat

> This is a stretch, but people can "go gaga" over something glorious by becoming "very enthusiastic and excited about someone or something". I'll be honest, I don't know about the "pretty cat".

thousands of reasons for hiding my hand

> This is a huge stretch, but babies may go "gaga" (ga-ga-goo-goo), so you should hold onto their hand?

Maybe it's time for my outfit to be bland

> Lady Gaga has many unique outfits that would be hard to call bland.

I can dive but not very deep, I guess I was born like that.

> This is what got me on the idea of "Gaga". One of Lady Gaga's famous songs is "Born this way". Unfortunately, I'm not sure about "I can dive but not very deep", it could possibly have a musical meaning that I'm not aware of?

Hint:

> See me twice, find my songs in shroud
>  Again, a reference to music, which led me to the idea of Lady Gaga.

Edit: Added some additional info to the last line's partial explanation.

Comment: Congratulations for finding the correct answer!! I am happy with the reasons for the first part (see me once), but for the second part there are many hints missing. You found one "song in shroud", can you find the others?

Comment: I can tell you that the words "a pretty cat" are the only words that are not part of a hint. I wrote this mainly for rhyming reasons.

Comment: As this is marked as partial answer, and because the answerer has not edited it since, I invite others to join and find the rest of the hints so I can mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: 'thousands of reasons for hiding my hand' can clue the rot13(fbatf Zvyyvba Ernfbaf & Cbxre Snpr)

Comment: 'I can dive ...'  line clues the rot13(fbat Funyybj ylevpf naq Obea Guvf Jnl)