# See me once, see me twice #13

Tags: riddle

Long time no see! Here is a fresh one for my "See me once" series:

> See me once, a pending action is ripe
> **Say** me twice, must I now help you wipe?
>
> See me once, used in an auxiliary way
> See me twice, my death is still mentioned today

<sub>If you are not familiar with my See me once riddles, I recommend you first have a look at the latest riddles in this series and their solutions:

[#7](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/74120/49661), [#8](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/74379/49661), [#9](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/74612/49661), [#10](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/74641/49661), [#11](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/74647/49661), [#12](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/85200/49661)</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are

> Do

See me once, a pending action is ripe

> **Do** means to perform an action

Say me twice, must I now help you wipe?

> Sounds like "doo-doo" (informal for what you do in a bathroom)

See me once, used in an auxiliary way

> Do is an auxiliary verb

See me twice, my death is still mentioned today

> [Dodo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodo) - a famously extinct animal, cf the phrase "Dead as a dodo".

Comment: Well, that was fast. Was it the say me twice hint that gave it away so fast? (edited back for the reply to make sense :D)

Comment: @kscherrer That is what I sort of focused in on to be fair. Nice puzzle.

Comment: So you did need to focus in somewhere at least, and didnt instantly see the answer. I can live with that :)