# See me once, see me twice #14

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> See me once, an archive to some and container to others
>   See me twice, clumsily fight for my amphibious brothers

I'm trying to keep things hard enough for this community, but I'll be ready to post another verse tomorrow if needed.

<sub>If you are not familiar with my See me once riddles, I recommend you first have a look at the latest riddles in this series and their solutions:

[#9](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/74612/49661), [#10](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/74641/49661), [#11](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/74647/49661), [#12](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/85200/49661), [#13](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/98893/49661)</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're a

> Jar. Jar can be a container, or a historical archive (as an artifact); and Jar Jar Binks is a (very) clumsy character (an amphibious one as well) from Star Wars.

Comment: Indeed it is. Well done!

Comment: "archive" probably refers to a .jar file