# See me once, See me twice #15

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> See me once, greetings to my brother in town
> See me twice, my effect is weighing you down

I'm prepared to give a hint in a day, if needed. Usually my riddles are solved very quickly though :) Good luck and have fun.

<sub>If you are not familiar with my See me once riddles, I recommend you first have a look at the latest riddles in this series and their solutions:

[#10](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/74641/49661), [#11](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/74647/49661), [#12](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/85200/49661), [#13](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/98893/49661), [#14](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/99023/49661)</sub>

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See me once, greetings to my brother in town

> yo - an informal greeting

See me twice, my effect is weighing you down

> [yo-yo effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yo-yo_effect) - the cyclical loss and gain of weight