# See me once, see me twice (fan-made)

Tags: riddle

You all know the rules, I'm sure. If not, see: [See me once, see me twice](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72528/see-me-once-see-me-twice)

See me once and I can act
See me twice and I can nap

See me once and I'm on a scale
See me twice and life I have failed

See me once and you will accomplish the thing
See me twice and listen to them sing

Comment: It warms my heart to see fanmade see-me-once riddles <3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Do

See me once and I can act

> **Do** - verb meaning to perform an action.

See me twice and I can nap

> I think **dodo** is another name for a baby's pacifier. 
>  **Edit:** there is also ["fais do-do"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fais_do-do) originating from a mother's gentle command to get their child to sleep.

See me once and I'm on a scale

> [Do, re, mi,...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solf%C3%A8ge)

See me twice and life I have failed

> **Dodo** - the extinct bird

See me once and you will accomplish the thing

> **Do** - can mean to achieve or complete.

See me twice and listen to them sing

> **Dodo** - not sure about this one but possibly the song of the extinct  bird. 
>  Could also possibly be referring to [The Dodos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dodos)

Comment: You got it nice and fast, lol. Unsurprising, these aren't typically the hardest. Close enough if not bang on on most of the clues, please expand on the last one though.

Comment: Good enough - if you look at the wikipedia disambiguation for dodo, though, you will see a list of artists who wrote songs called 'dodo' including David Bowie and Stromae. This was my original intention.

Answer (score 2):

## Partial

Are you:

> LA

See me once and I can act

> L.A. - Los Angeles, Hollywood - full of actors

See me twice and I can nap

> [La la land](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/la-la%20land) (note, it's also a movie!)

See me once and I'm on a scale

> La weight loss diet plan?

See me twice and life I have failed

> unsure

See me once and you will accomplish the thing

> unsure

See me twice and listen to them sing

> Singing is often represented as "La la!"